# Does slow upserts with write concern unacknowledged and many yields indicate problems with my query?

Tags: mongodb

I am doing many upserts to a collection that also receives a lot of find queries. My upserts have write concern unacknowledged. Many of these upserts appear in the mongo log with runtimes above 800ms and yields above 20. The number of inprog operations on the server seems stable around 20 with peaks around 40.

The collection contains ~15 million documents.

Does these long query times indicate that the mongo server cannot keep up with the incoming data, or is it just postponing the unacknowledged queries in a controlled manner?

The documents in the collection look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53c65f9f995bce51e4d84ecb"),
    "items" : [
        "53216cf7e4b04d3fa854a4d0",
        "53218be4e4b0a79ba7fee19a"
    ],
    "score" : 1,
    "other" : [
        "b09b2c99-e4f3-48a2-990d-4b2090cc9666",
        "b09b2c99-e4f3-48a2-990d-4b2090cc9666"
    ]
}
```

I have the following indexes

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "dbname.stuff"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "items" : 1,
            "score" : -1
        },
        "name" : "items_1_score_-1",
        "ns" : "dbname.stuff",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

The slow upserts look like this in the log

```
update dbname.stuff query: { items: [ "52ea4da1e4b035b15423f8f5", "53c7cf43e4b007135ca60114" ] } update: { $inc: { score: 6 }, $setOnInsert: { others: [ "64a7e6b1-2a0a-4374-ac9c-fbf2de7cbb48", "b9e07cda-14c8-45e4-95cc-f0f4c5bc410c" ] } } nscanned:0 nscannedObjects:0 nMatched:1 nModified:0 fastmodinsert:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:16 locks(micros) w:46899 1752ms
```

Comment: Would help if you posted some code and possibly a sample document as well as some indication of the size of your collection. The likely problem here though is indexes, in some form or another.

Comment: More information added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acknowledgement on write or "Write Concern" does not affect overall query performance, just really the time that could possibly be taken while the client waits for the acknowledgement. So if you are more or less in "fire and forget" mode, then your client is not held up but the write operations can still possible take as while.

In this case, it seems your working set is actually quite large. It is also worth considering that this is "server wide" and not just constrained to one collection or even database. The general case here is you cannot have enough RAM for what you are trying to load and you are running into paging. See the "yields" counter.

Upserts require to "find" the matching document in the index, so even if there is no match you still need to "scan" and find out if the item exists. This means loading the index into memory. As such you have a few choices:

1. Remodel to make these write "insert only", and aggregate "counter" type values in background processes, but basically not in real time.
2. Add more RAM within your means.
3. Time to shard so you can have several "shards" in your cluster that have a capable amount of RAM to deal with the working set sizes.

Nothing is easy here, and depending on what your application actually requires then all offer varying levels of solution. Indeed though if you are prepared to live without "write acknowledgements" in general, then you might need to work around the rest of your application bearing with "eventual consistency" of those writes actually being available to be read.

Comment: Does this mean that yields only (primarily?) happen on paging?

Comment: @JacobOettinger Not **only**, but it can be a large cause also along heavy insert operations. I tried to keep this in the scope of "programming" solutions, being in line with questions on stack overflow. Anything else really becomes a professional server or DBA type discussion, for which there other sites on the stackexchange network. But it basically stands to reason that even with a single collection in the 15M document range that you are running out of RAM, and have likely only gone as far as replica sets if not simply a single host.

Comment: I do have replicas, but anyway. The server has other big collections so paging is an issue. Changing to a "insert and aggregate later" approach seems like a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobOettinger See how you go, but that was largely the point. It's always worth considering "re-modelling" at various points of development, and something MongoDB is fairly flexible with. But always keep in mind that at some point your application is likely to grow to where sharding becomes a necessity. So it is worth considering plans around that as well.